# Horizontal/Vertical alignment in list

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Ok so I'm trying to do that for 1 long day right now, without find a correct solution.

I'm working with Wordpress (woocommerce) and Divi theme.

**What I have :**

When a user click on a product, the description is displayed but others products go below the description of the previous product (see picture)

**What I would like :**

A list of products (`ul li`) that I have to display on a line (3 products by line, it's ok for that).

When a user click a product, the description of it is displayed below the product (in full width), without changing the position of others products.

In responsive, the description must be displayed below the associated product, and not under the last product

I don't know how to add code in Wordpress (woocommerce). I need a place where product's description is available.

The HTML is added by the BO, it's just a list of product :

```
<ul class="products">
    <li class="product">
        <span class="et_shop_image">
            <img src="#">
            <h3>Product name</h3>
        </span>
    </li>

    <div class="description">
        <h3>Product name</h3>
        <p class="text-description">This is a description</p>
    </div>

    <li class="product">
        <span class="et_shop_image">
            <img src="#">
            <h3>Product name 1</h3>
        </span>
    </li>

    <div class="description">
        <h3>Product name</h3>
        <p class="text-description">This is a description</p>
    </div>
</ul>
```

The `div` with `description` class is added in `content-product.php`, after `</li>`.

JS :

```
$('li.product').click(function () {
    var currentContent = $(this).siblings('.description');
    $('.description').not(currentContent).slideUp();
    currentContent.slideToggle().siblings('.description');
});
```

CSS (nothing very interessant) :

```
ul.products {
  margin-top: 5% !important;
}

li.product {
  border: solid 3px rgb(127, 199, 41);
  border-radius: 20px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 9px !important;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 280px;
}

.active-product {
  &:after {
    content: '';
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: $gris-clair;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: -58px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}

.description{
  float: left;
  color: $bleu;
  background: $gris-clair;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px 0 20px 0;
  display: none;

  .titre-description{
    color: $bleu;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

This is before click (note that it missed a space between lasts products)

[image]
And after click :
[image]

Comment: Please post css code, you need to make a position absolute on the tooltip

Comment: Oh yeah I forgotten to post CSS, I edit my post ^^

Comment: Can you provide the css for `.description` please ?

Comment: Yes, sorry .. It's in the post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this...

```
ul.products {
    margin-top: 5% !important;

    position: relative;
}

.description{
    color: $bleu;
    background: $gris-clair;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px 0 20px 0;
    display: none;

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok I see what you want to do. But it's not working. The description pass over the footer. And in RDW it's too low.